# Apache Solr sort by function

Tags: apache, solr

Trying  to sort a query by a field closest to today. From what i understand the sub function only allows references to the document. Is it possible to perform this via other means?

This is the error returned by Solr:
sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: sub(NOW,StartDate)','code'=>400}}

e.g.
sort=sub(NOW, StartDate) asc

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ms` function if you're planning to do arithmetic operations on dates. This will convert the date to an integer.

In fact, [the examples for `ms`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions) shows exactly what you're trying to do:

```
ms(NOW,mydatefield)
```

.. which is described as

> ms(a,b) : Returns the number of milliseconds that b occurs before a (that is, a - b)

Comment: Thank-you Mats for your feedback, led me down the right path to a function that should have worked but didn't due to legacy types configured in sunspot. The schema.xml has it's base fields setup as legacy date, int, float, long, int. The following post resolved this issue https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-sunspot/hL4-0NqNnqA